# Fermion mass correction always proportional to it's mass? even in case of mixing?

Tags: mass, quantum-electrodynamics, renormalization, fermions, self-energy

In QED, it is obvious that one-loop correction to the mass of the fermion ($\psi$) is proportional to its bare mass. However, it is not very clear to me whether it is general even in the case when there exists a vertex between two different fermions $\psi$, $\chi$, and photon $\gamma$.

To be more specific, I followed the logic given between equations (7.15) ~ (7.29) in the Peskin & Schroeder QFT textbook. According to equation (7.19), $\Sigma_2$ is proportional to the bare mass ($m_0$) of $\psi$ since $\psi$ runs inside the loop. However, I think that if $\chi$ runs inside the loop (in the case vertex between $\psi$, $\chi$, and photon $\gamma$ exists), the mass correction for $\psi$ will not proportional to the bare mass of $\psi$. (From the argument of Peskin & Schroeder, it will be proportional to ($2m_\chi-xm_0$).)

In this case, I am very confused because even in the limit $m_0\rightarrow0$ there is some mass correction in the loop level. Is this natural? Or is there anything that I missed?